# Object tree with hyperledger composer queries

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I sucessfuly used queries for simple cases, like the one in the tutorials. But when I try match referenced object fields, my queries keep returning nothing.

Exemple: I want all Exams that refere to a patient called "joe"

Here is my model:

Patient:

```
asset Patient identified by id {
    o String id
    o String clinicalPid
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
}
```

Exam:

```
asset Exam identified by id {
    o String id
    o ExamType type
    o BodyPart bodyPart
    o String protocol 
    o Long radiationValue
    o DateTime examDate
    --> Clinic clinic
    --> Patient patient
}
```

And My query:

```
query selectExamByPatientName  {
  description: "Select all Exam using the patient firstname"
  statement:
      SELECT ch.hcuge.radiopassport.Exam
          WHERE ( patient.firstName == _$patientName)
}
```

Thanks,

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

per Rocketchat:

you can't do that [presently (traverse another registry for a match, 'relational' style) in queries right now, as CouchDB not a relational database